# subclassing tables.Group class

Tags: pytables

Is it allowable to subclass tables.Group?

The following code works fine

```
In [1]: import tables

In [2]: class Friendly_group(tables.Group):
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return 'hello!'
   ...:     

In [3]: hf = tables.open_file('data', mode='w')

In [4]: fgroup = Friendly_group(hf.root, 'fgroup', new=True)

In [5]: hf
Out[5]: 
File(filename=data, title='', mode='w', root_uep='/', filters=Filters(complevel=0, shuffle=False, fletcher32=False))
/ (RootGroup) ''
/fgroup (Friendly_group) ''


In [6]: hf.root.fgroup
Out[6]: hello!
```

But after reading back, that group stops being friendly

```
In [7]: hf.close()

In [8]: hf = tables.open_file('data', mode='r')

In [9]: hf
Out[9]: 
File(filename=data, title='', mode='r', root_uep='/', filters=Filters(complevel=0, shuffle=False, fletcher32=False))
/ (RootGroup) ''
/fgroup (Group) ''


In [10]: hf.root.fgroup
Out[10]: 
/fgroup (Group) ''
  children := []
```

SO checker forces me to add some details to this post, but I really don't know how can I increase clearness of my question, so please, excuse me for this dummy piece of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  The missing piece that you do not have that is needed for depersistence is to override the `_c_classid` class attribute.  You probably want to look at other group subclasses that are present in `tables/group.py`.  For instance, take the TransactionGroupG (stripped of some backwards compatibility features),

```
class TransactionGroupG(NotLoggedMixin, Group):
    _c_classid = 'TRANSGROUP'

    def _g_width_warning(self):
        warnings.warn("""\
the number of transactions is exceeding the recommended maximum (%d);\
be ready to see PyTables asking for *lots* of memory and possibly slow I/O"""
                      % (self._v_max_group_width,), PerformanceWarning)
```

This is fairly minimal.